# not able to get column id in javascript

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I am trying to get the id of the input field(PEPM) which is enclosed in the column(PEPMColumn).I am trying the below code and i am getting the error in console ' TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null'

```
window.onload = function() {
            alert('test');
            var PEPM = document.getElementById("{!$Component.frmProducer.pbProducer.pageblockTable.PEPMColumn.PEPM}").value;
            alert(PEPM);
        }
```

I tried to segregate the path and i got the error after alert alert(PEPM2);

```
window.onload = function() {
    alert('test');
    var PEPM = document.getElementById("{!$Component.frmProducer}").value;
    alert(PEPM);
    var PEPM1 = document.getElementById("{!$Component.frmProducer.pbProducer}").value;
    alert(PEPM1);
    var PEPM2 = document.getElementById("{!$Component.frmProducer.pbProducer.pageblockTable}").value;
    alert(PEPM2);
    var PEPM3= document.getElementById("{!$Component.frmProducer.pbProducer.pageblockTable.PEPMColumn}").value;
    alert(PEPM3);
    var PEPM4 = document.getElementById("{!$Component.frmProducer.pbProducer.pageblockTable.PEPMColumn.PEPM}").value;
    alert(PEPM4);
}
```

can't we get the value of column in Javascript or is it something that i am doing wrong.May be some fresh eyes can catch the issue

Comment: We will need to see your dom to help.

Comment: I do not have that much handson on JS.Could you please let me know how i can i provide you the DOM?

Comment: Your vf markup. Post that

Comment: i think as you are doing the piece of code in window.onload it is unable to get that Id and hence it is giving you the error of null. Can you place that piece of code in some js function and onclick of any event check whether you're able to get the value.

Comment: @rcs I dont think thats the issue as window.onload() fires when the dom is ready and all the images are loaded.